# Structure character data into data frame

Tags: r, rstudio

I used rvest package in R to scrape some web data but I am having a lot of trouble getting it into a usuable format.

My data currently looks like this:

```
     test
     [1] "v.  Philadelphia"                                           
     [2] "TD GardenRegular Season"                                    
     [3] "PTS: 23. Jayson TatumREB: 10. M. MorrisAST: 7. Kyrie Irving"
     [4] "PTS: 23. Joel EmbiidREB: 15. Ben SimmonsAST: 8. Ben Simmons"
     [5] "100.7 - 83.4" 
     [6] "@  Toronto"                                                         
     [7] "Air Canada Centre Regular Season"                              
     [8] "PTS: 21. Kyrie IrvingREB: 10. Al HorfordAST: 9. Al Horford" 
     [9] "PTS: 31. K. LeonardREB: 10. K. LeonardAST: 7. F. VanVleet"  
     [10] "115.6 - 103.3"
```

Can someone help me perform the correct operations in order to have it look like this (as a data frame) and provide the code, I would really appreciate it:

```
     Opponent       Venue   
     Philadelphia   TD Garden
     Toronto        Air Canada Centre
```

I do not need any of the other information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me know if there are any issues :)

```
# put your data in here
input <- c("v. Philadelphia", "TD GardenRegular Season", 
           "", "", "",
           "@ Toronto", "Air Canada Centre Regular Season",
           "", "", "")
index <- 1:length(input)

# raw table format
out_raw <- data.frame(Opponent = input[index%%5==1],
                      Venue = input[index%%5==2])

# using stringi package
install.packages("stringi")
library(stringi)

# copy and clean up
out_clean <- out_raw
out_clean$Opponent <- stri_extract_last_regex(out_raw$Opponent, "(?<=\\s).*$")
out_clean$Venue <- trimws(gsub("Regular Season", "", out_raw$Venue))
out_clean
```